# Angular TSLint: Only allow camelCase, do Not allow Pascal case

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, angular10

We are writing code in Angular, and only want to allow lower-case first letter, Camel case. For example, ProductName should show a display warning/error (since its capitalized).

How can I allow only camelCase in TSLint, and not allow Pascal (Uppercase)?

```
this.product.ProductName = 5;
```

The following is not showing errors in usage, only in the Class component itself,

```
export class Product {
  ProductId: number;
  ProductName: string;
}
```

**TS Lint Settings:**

```
"variable-name": {
  "options": [
   "ban-keywords",
   "check-format"
 ]
```

} ,

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/variable-name/

Comment: As you can see in that link, it doesn't allow Pascal case by default, only camel case and all upper case. There does not appear to be a way of disallowing all upper case. TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint...https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration

Comment: @MarkThomas51 - I didn't downvote you.  But yes, I understand you're just doing your job.  +1 ;)  Per Heretic Monkey's suggestion, you *might* be able to accomplish this with an ESLint regex: [require identifiers to match a specified regular expression (id-match)](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/id-match#require-identifiers-to-match-a-specified-regular-expression-id-match)

Answer (score 0):

Set allow-pascal-case.

```
"variable-name": {
  "options": [
    "ban-keywords",
    "check-format",
    "allow-pascal-case",
    "allow-leading-underscore"
  ]
},
```